# automate firebase target config in firebase.json

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, automation, firebase-hosting

hey I have been working on setting up multiple domains setup using commandline.
But when I run the commands from firebase hosting they does not update the firebase.json file.
According to documentation "https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites" I need to manually configure the setup. But I want an automated way like when I run the target command it itself updates the firebase.json file.
What I am thinking is writing custom script which gets user input and then updates the script based on given target and public folder.
But is their any official way of doing this? without writing custom script?

I have tried the documentation which is https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites and all commands based on the documentations. also asked chatGPT,bing chat and bard. No one have given me current answer or official answer without writing third party script.
Is it possible that we can really do this or not?

Comment: Have you also tried [Set up deploy targets for your sites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites#set_up_deploy_targets) and still the firebase.json was not updated with the provided changes ?

Comment: yeah, done everything. but major issue which was editing the firebase.json file without using custom script.
But somehow I convinced client to use custom script and issue got resolved.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your resolved as an answer ? So the other community members will also get the answer for this question.

Comment: yeah sure why not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I searched a lot but didn't find anything useful so here is my own script which will do this part.

```
const fs = require('fs');

try {
    // Read the firebase.json file
    const firebaseJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./firebase.json', 'utf8'));

    let hostingObject = firebaseJson?.hosting;
    const args = process.argv.slice(2);
    let targetDir = "";
    let publicDir = "";

    if (Array.isArray(hostingObject)) {

        // Check if --target and --public args are provided
        const hasTargetArg = args.includes('--target');
        const hasPublicArg = args.includes('--public');

        // Get the values of --target and --public args
        const targetArgValue = hasTargetArg ? args[args.indexOf('--target') + 1] : null;
        const publicArgValue = hasPublicArg ? args[args.indexOf('--public') + 1] : null;

        // Create a new hosting configuration object with updated target and public
        const updatedHostingConfig = {
            target: hasTargetArg ? targetArgValue : hostingObject[0]?.target,
            public: hasPublicArg ? publicArgValue : hostingObject[0]?.public
        };

        // Append the updated hosting configuration to the existing array
        hostingObject.push(updatedHostingConfig);
        firebaseJson.hosting = hostingObject;
    } else if (typeof hostingObject === 'object') {
        const defaultTarget = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./.firebaserc', 'utf8'))?.projects?.default;
        let tempHostingObject = [];
        tempHostingObject.push({...hostingObject});
        tempHostingObject[0].target = defaultTarget;
        targetDir = args.includes('--target') ? args[args.indexOf('--target') + 1] : null;
        publicDir = args.includes('--public') ? args[args.indexOf('--public') + 1] : null;
        let newtempHostingObject = {...hostingObject};
        newtempHostingObject.target = targetDir;
        newtempHostingObject.public = publicDir;
        tempHostingObject.push(newtempHostingObject);
        hostingObject = tempHostingObject;

        firebaseJson.hosting = hostingObject;
    }

    fs.writeFileSync('firebase.json', JSON.stringify(firebaseJson, null, 2));
    console.log("Updated firebase.json with targetDir:", targetDir, "and publicDir:", publicDir);
} catch (err) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', err);
}
```

and to run this we can give arguments as this:

```
node app.js --target targetName --public buildFolder
```